# Passar variável Javascript/Jquery para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, variáveis, session

Estou tentando passar uma variável de um arquivo *JavaScript* externo para *PHP*, pegando o valor dela novamente, mas dá um erro quando tento passar para *PHP* e fazer a requisição do *POST* em *Ajax*. De todas as formas que tentei, a variável não *passa*.

Eu pego o *POST* dela e gravo em uma sessão, depois dou um `var_dump` nessa sessão e aparece *NULL* sempre.

Quando coloco para testar uma variável com valor qualquer no arquivo *PHP* do *POST*, a `$_SESSION` fica *NULL* e parece que não houve requisição, mesmo tendo um *refresh* na página.

**Trecho do arquivo *date.js*:**

```
 saveBtn.on("click", function() {
      var inputName = $("input[name=mat]").val();
      var inputDate = $("input[name=date]").val();
      var inputNotes = $("textarea[name=notes]").val();
      var inputTag = $("select[name=tags]")
        .find(":selected")
        .text();
```

> ----------------ag-monitoria.php------------ ( uma parte php )

( Aqui pega a variável e transforma em uma sessão )

```
if(isset($_POST['dataform'])) {

  $_SESSION['materia'] = $_POST['tags'];
  $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];
  $_SESSION['obs'] = $_POST['notes'];
}
```

> Segue o form no HTML ---

```
    <form id="addEvent" method="post">
      <h2>Data</h2>
      <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required>
               <div class='col-sm-4'>
                </div>
      <h2>Observações</h2>
      <textarea placeholder="Observações" name="notes" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <h2>Matéria</h2>
      <select name="tags" id="mat">
          <?php 

          $add = new USER();

                      $stmt = $add->runQuery("SELECT * FROM materias ORDER BY id_mat");
        $stmt->execute();
        $m=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($m as $mat) {
          $materia = $mat['materia'];
          ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $materia;?>"><?php echo $materia;?></option>   
            <?php }?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 


$('#addEvent').on('submit', function() {
   event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ag-monitoria.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#addEvent').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {

      }

    });

    return false;

});
});
</script>
        <input type="submit" href="javascript:;" class="o-btn js-event__save md-trigger md-setperspective" data-modal="modal-18" value="AGENDAR" id="dataform" name="dataform">
    </form>
```

Comment: Você iniciou a sessão no PHP usando o método  `session_start() `? Fora isso, adicione a parte do código PHP, onde você salva a sessão para que possamos entender melhor a lógica.

Comment: Sim, em todos os arquivos PHP ele carrega um método de classe onde inicia a sessão, já que a página é de um painel onde tem um usuário logado.